# how to use a tag as input to a script in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

In xsl I need to convert a string with a date into a proper date. I am attempting to use a vb script in the xsl to do that.

It works fine if I assign the string to a variable first

```
<xsl:variable name="date1">
               <xsl:value-of select="datetag"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

then I can do

```
<tst><xsl:value-of select="extra:myscript(string($date1))"/></tst>
```

But I can't figure out how to use the"datetag" directly without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I did get how to call a sub temple for the datetag by qualify the apply templates with a select
<xsl:apply-templates select="datetag"/>

But I am not sure this is better than using a variable..
What I really want to do is addressing the tag directly inline

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use? How does the VBScript function code look like exactly, does it expect a node or a string or a date? Show us minimal but complete and well-formed samples of XML input, XSLT you have, result you want and result you get.

Comment: @vikjon0 Sounds like you want `<xsl:value-of select="extra:myscript(datetag)"/>`. -- P.S. Is it really necessary to have an external function for this? You could handle it by XSLT-native string manipulation, I think.

Comment: msxsl for the moment. I just figured it out. You are right to ask what the function expect as input. 
It was a combination of me not understanding to correctly use an xpath in that context and not converting to a string while trying to figure that out.

All I needed was
<xsl:value-of select="extra:myscript(string(./datetag))"/>

Now I just have to figure out why the script tags adds attributes to the out: <top xmlns:extra="urn:extra-functions">

Comment: @ michael.hor257k Yes, I think that would have been enough but I needed to add string() as well, so the problem was really the function crashing. Completely new to xsl.

It can probably be done with xsl, but as you can see I am not good with xsl. 
Also, I will need to add UTC offset and I know how to fix that using vbs and db query.

Comment: @vikjon0 "*why the script tags adds attributes to the out: <top xmlns:extra="urn:extra-functions">*" Lookup `exclude-result-prefixes`. P.S. They are not attributes.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see your comment in time but I reviewed the different samples I had collected and found it. It was not included in the original sample I copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Not really an issue only some confusion while testing.

All I need is

```
<xsl:value-of select="extra:myscript(string(./datetag))"/>
```

I did of course test this and a lot of variation but not the correct variant in combination with string().